# Using a C# keyword in WebApi action

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am writing an action in a controller that is replacing a legacy web service.  The problem is that I need to use a C# keyword (ref) as a parameter.  The code below won't compile because I am using the reserved word ref.  So how can I setup WebApi Routing to deal with this?

Example:

```
public class MyController : BaseController
{
    [ActionName("RedirectToItem")]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage RedirectToItem(int ref)
    {
         // Do stuff...
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `@ref` in the method definition to escape the keyword and avoid the keyword collision.

Comment: Specifically, the @ sign in front of a variable escapes it and allows you to use reserved words. Same for e.g. @class.